# How can I make my JAVA installation file install JVM along with it?

Tags: installation, jvm, windows-installer

Is there a solution to create an installer for my JAVA application, which will install also JVM if needed?

I'm asking this, because I don't want the users to try install my application, and get a "YOU DON'T HAVE JVM" style message. They will not know what to do or how to handle it...

Answer (score 0):

Would Wix suit you, it allows you to create a MSI and set dependencies?

Check [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Acually if you're using Netbeans you can do it easily: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJf10Xq_Td4